# Unable to re-read file despite seek()

Tags: r

I am unable to re-read a file, despite performing a seek() to the beginning of file

```
> con <- file("AJOVPH.csv", open="rt", encoding="utf-8")
> x<- readLines(con)
> seek(con,0)
[1] 1388
> x<- readLines(con)
> x
character(0)
> seek(con,0)
[1] 0
> read.csv(con, comment.char = "#", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
>
```

I would expect that con is back to the beginning and I can extract the relevant information.

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? From the `?seek` help page: "Use of seek on Windows is discouraged. We have found so many errors in the Windows implementation of file positioning that users are advised to use it only at their own risk, and asked not to waste the R developers' time with bug reports on Windows' deficiencies." You'd just need to close the file and re-open.

Comment: @MrFlick i'm on linux

Comment: Does `isSeekable(con)` return TRUE after you open the connection?

Comment: @MrFlick I tracked it down to being the connection opened as text. It works if I open it as "r". I suspect it can't perform seeking if there's a multibyte encoding in between (an error would be nice...).  But the question remains. Can I re-read a file opened as "rt"?

Comment: @MrFlick @StefanoBorini you can re-read a connection in `rt` - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 19.10 running R 3.6.2 here.
The test run below shows that it's possible to `seek` a file open in open mode `"rt"` and reread it.

First, create a CSV file.

```
out <- data.frame(colA = letters[1:5], colB = 1:5)
write.csv(out, "test.csv")
```

Now read, seek, read.

```
f <- file("test.csv", open = "rt")
isSeekable(f)
#[1] TRUE

x1 <- readLines(f)
seek(f, where = 0, rw = "read", origin = "start")
#[1] 67
x2 <- readLines(f)
identical(x1, x2)
#[1] TRUE

close(f)
```

Can this be done with `read.csv` too?

```
f <- file("test.csv", open = "rt")

df1 <- read.csv(f)
seek(f, where = 0, rw = "read", origin = "start")
#[1] 67
df2 <- read.csv(f)
identical(df1, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Yes, it can. Time to tidy up.

```
close(f)
unlink("test.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `seek` when you select text re-encoding to "UTF-8" in `file`

This is in the help file for `seek` :

> None of these should be expected to work on text-mode connections with re-encoding selected.

To show this, I can replicate your problem:

```r
write.csv(data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = letters[1:5]), "my.csv")

con <- file("my.csv", "rt", encoding = "UTF-8")
x   <- readLines(con)
seek(con, 0)
#> [1] 149
y   <- readLines(con)
close(con)
y
#> character(0)
```

And I can fix it by running exactly the same code, except removing `encoding = "UTF-8"` from `file()` :

```r
write.csv(data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = letters[1:5]), "my.csv")

con <- file("my.csv", "rt")
x   <- readLines(con)
seek(con, 0)
#> [1] 149
y   <- readLines(con)
close(con)
y
#> [1] "\"\",\"a\",\"b\""               "\"1\",-0.989039082667898,\"a\""
#> [3] "\"2\",0.304563032422747,\"b\""  "\"3\",0.876861603714057,\"c\"" 
#> [5] "\"4\",0.430749580251368,\"d\""  "\"5\",-0.464997645114009,\"e\""
```

If you specifically want to read the file as UTF-8, open it in `rt` mode and specify the encoding in `readLines`

```r
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = c(letters[1:4], "\u0986"))
write.csv(df, "my.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

con <- file("my.csv", "rt")
x   <- readLines(con, encoding = "UTF-8")
seek(con, 0)
#> [1] 149
y   <- readLines(con, encoding = "UTF-8")
close(con)
y
#> [1] "\"\",\"a\",\"b\""                   "\"1\",0.250961986479494,\"a\""     
#> [3] "\"2\",-0.874891848118619,\"b\""     "\"3\",-0.394876527760101,\"c\""    
#> [5] "\"4\",0.358779166473852,\"d\""      "\"5\",1.5209073992579,\"<U+0986>\""
```

Comment: ``None of these should be expected to work on text-mode connections with re-encoding selected``. Interesting. I read that phrase but I don't get what they meant with "re-encoding". There's no re-encoding going on. The file is utf-8 and I am reading it in utf-8. Also, weird that I don't at least get an error message...

Comment: @StefanoBorini the file is encoded as utf8, but to read it as utf8 text, the connection needs to interpret the multi-byte characters. You wouldn't want it to seek into the middle of a multi-byte character. The result of starting to read it from there would be garbage.

Comment: @StefanoBorini so it is re-encoding between disk and memory - from an array of bytes to an array of wide characters.